# Isomorphism of Lie modules $\text{Hom}_\mathfrak g (V\otimes W,Z) = \text{Hom}_\mathfrak g(V, \text{Hom}_k(W,Z)). $

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, tensor-products

I'm trying to check that if $\mathfrak  g$ is a Lie algebra and and $V,W,Z$ are $\mathfrak  g$-modules, then there is an isomorphism
$$
\text{Hom}_\mathfrak g  (V\otimes W,Z) \cong \text{Hom}_\mathfrak  g(V, \text{Hom}_k(W,Z)). \tag{$\star$}
$$
where for vector spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ the set $\text{Hom}_\mathfrak g  (V_1,V_2)$ is the subset of $\text{Hom}_k (V_1,V_2)$ (notice the subindex is $k$ instead of $\mathfrak  g$) that consists of linear maps compatible with the action of $\mathfrak  g$ on $V_1$ and $V_2$. I thought I found a natural isomorphism between (notice the subindex is $k$ instead of $\mathfrak  g$)
$$
\text{Hom}_k (V,W) \cong  \text{Hom}_k(V, \text{Hom}_k(W,Z)).
$$
described as follows:
define a map
\begin{align*}
L_1 : \text{Hom}_k ( V \otimes W , Z) &\longrightarrow \text{Hom}_k(V , \text{Hom}_k (W,Z))\\
T & \longmapsto \big\{ v \mapsto T(v \otimes \bullet)\big\}.
\end{align*}
and define a map
\begin{align*}
 L_2: \text{Hom}_k(V , \text{Hom}_k (W,Z)) &\longrightarrow \text{Hom}_k ( V \otimes W , Z)\\
\Phi & \longmapsto \big\{ u \otimes w \mapsto \Phi(u)(w) \big\}
\end{align*}
These maps are clearly linear, and I think I've proven that they are inverse to each other.

This seems so natural that I can't help but think that this will restrict to the isomorphism desired in $(\star)$, but I haven't been able to show this. Is it false? Is my attempt misguided?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Notice that the $\mathfrak g$-action on the tensor product and the Hom sets is made so that this should indeed just be the restriction of the general adjunction map. Cf. my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3699481/96384.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg So in particular this result does not need the assumption that the spaces have finite dimension?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Now I'm not sure why I was even stuck haha, I just needed the extra motivation your comment gave me ;)