# Representations of the symplectic Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sp}_{4}\mathbb C$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am self studing classical Lie algebras and their representations from the book *Representation Theory – A First Course* by William Fulton and Joe Harris.

In the chapter on representations of symplectic Lie algebras $\mathfrak{sp}_{4}\mathbb{C}$, the four-dimensional vector space $V$ is defined as the standard representation of $\mathfrak{sp}_{4}\mathbb{C}$. They next consider the exterior power $\bigwedge^{2} V$.

I have difficulty understanding the statement “$\bigwedge^{2} V$ cannot be irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{sp}_{4} \mathbb{C}$, since the corresponding group action of Lie group $\mathrm{Sp}_{4} \mathbb{C}$ on $V$ by definition preserves the skew form $Q \in \bigwedge^{2} V$”.

I am not quite comfortable with Lie algebra and Lie group association.
Can anybody please explain this to me?
Moreover I am not sure why the skew symmetric form $Q$ belongs to $\bigwedge^{2} V$.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence: in my copy of the book, it states instead that “$Q ∈ ⋀^2 V^* ≅ ⋀^2 V$”. So they claim that $Q$ is an element of $⋀^2 V^*$, and then also claim that $⋀^2 V^*$ is isomorphic to $⋀^2 V$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's a mistake from my end.

Answer (score 4):

Let us recall some background on the actions of Lie algebras of bilinear forms.
Let $$ be a $$-Lie algebra and let $V$ be a representation of $$, where $$ is some field with $\operatorname{char}  ≠ 2$.

- An element $v$ of $V$ is called *invariant* if $xv = 0$ for all $x ∈ $.

Note that a non-zero invariant element always spans a one-dimensional trivial subrepresentation.
An irreducible representation must therefore not contain any non-zero invariant elements, unless it is the one-dimensional trivial representation.

- A bilinear form $β \colon V × V \to $ is called *$$-invariant* if
  $$
    β(xv, w) + β(v, xw) = 0
    \qquad
    \text{for all $x ∈ $ and all $v, w ∈ V$.}
  $$
  If $$ is the Lie algebra of a Lie group $G$, then this corresponds (roughly) to $β$ being $G$-invariant in the sense that
  $$
    β(gv, gw) = β(v, w)
    \qquad
    \text{for all $g ∈ G$, $v, w ∈ V$.}
  $$

This notion of “$$-invariant” is a special case of the general notion of “invariant”.

- The vector space of bilinear maps $\newcommand{\Bil}{\operatorname{Bil}}\Bil^2(V, ℂ)$ becomes again a representation of $$ via
  $$
    (x β)(v, w) = β(xv, w) + β(v, xw)
    \qquad
    \text{for all $x ∈ $, $β ∈ \Bil^2(V, )$, $v, w ∈ V$.}
  $$
  A bilinear form $β$ is $$-invariant if and only if it invariant in the general sense.

We have some standard homomorphism/isomorphisms regarding $\Bil^2(V, )$.

- The usual isomorphism of vector spaces $\Bil^2(V, ) ≅ (V ⊗ V)^*$ is an isomorphism of representations.
  The usual injective linear map $V^* ⊗ V^* \to (V ⊗ V)^*$ is a homomorphism of representations.
  If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then it is thus an isomorphism of representations.

We can also restrict our attention to alternating bilinear forms, or symmetric bilinear forms.

- Let $\newcommand{\Alt}{\operatorname{Alt}} \Alt^2(V, )$ be the linear subspace of $\Bil^2(V, )$ consisting of alternating bilinear forms.
  This is $$-subrepresentation of $\Bil^2(V, )$.
  The usual isomorphism of vector spaces $\Alt^2(V, ) ≅ (⋀^2 V)^*$ is an isomorphism of representations.
  The usual injective linear map $⋀^2 (V^*) \to (⋀^2 V)^*$ is a homomorphism of representations.
  If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then it is thus an isomorphism of representations.
- Let $\newcommand{\Sym}{\operatorname{Sym}} \Sym^2(V, )$ be the linear subspace of $\Bil^2(V, )$ consisting of alternating bilinear forms.
  This is $$-subrepresentation of $\Bil^2(V, )$.
  The usual isomorphism of vector spaces $\newcommand{\Symp}{\operatorname{S}} \Sym^2(V, ) ≅ \Symp^2(V)^*$ is an isomorphism of representations.
  The usual injective linear map $\Symp^2(V^*) \to \Symp^2(V)^*$ is a homomorphism of representations.
  If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then it is thus an isomorphism of representations.

A bilinear form on a vector space $W$ is the same as a linear map $W \to W^*$.
If $W$ is finite-dimensional, then the linear map $W \to W^*$ is an isomorphism if and only if the corresponding bilinear form is non-degenerate.
We can do essentially the same for isomorphisms of representations $V ≅ V^*$.

- Every bilinear form $β$ on $V$ determines a linear map
  $$
    β' \colon V \longrightarrow V^* \,, \quad v \longmapsto β(v, -) \,.
  $$
  The bilinear form $β$ is $$-invariant if and only if this linear map $β'$ is a homomorphism of representations.
  Consequently, if $V$ is finite-dimensional and $β$ is both $$-invariant and non-degenerate, then $β'$ is an isomorphism of representations $V ≅ V^*$.

As a consequence, we have the following:

> Suppose that the representation $V$ is finite-dimensional, and that it admits a non-degenerate, $$-invariant bilinear form $β$.
>
> 1. There exist isomorphisms of representations
>    \begin{gather*}
>      \Bil^2(V, ) ≅ (V ⊗ V)^* ≅ V^* ⊗ V^* ≅ V ⊗ V \,,      \\[0.5em]
>      \Alt^2(V) ≅ \Bigl( ⋀^2 V \Bigr)^* ≅ ⋀^2 V^* ≅ ⋀^2 V \,, \\[0.5em]
>      \Sym^2(V) ≅ \Symp^2(V)^* ≅ \Symp^2(V^*) ≅ \Symp^2(V) \,.
>    \end{gather*}
> 2. The bilinear form $β$ is an invariant element of $\Bil^2(V, )$, whence $V ⊗ V$ cannot be irreducible unless it the one-dimensional trivial representation.
>    This requires $V$ to be one-dimensional.
> 3. Suppose that $β$ is alternating.
>    It it then an invariant element of $\Alt^2(V, )$, whence $⋀^2 V$ cannot be irreducible unless it is one-dimensional and trivial.
>    This requires $V$ to be two-dimensional.
> 4. Suppose that $β$ is symmetric.
>    It it then an invariant element of $\Sym^2(V, )$, whence $\Symp^2(V)$ cannot be irreducible unless it is one-dimensional and trivial.
>    This requires $V$ to be one-dimensional.

---

We can pretty much directly apply this general argumentation to the given situation.
We only need to know that the form $Q$ is $_4(ℂ)$-invariant.
Depending on the given definition of $_4(ℂ)$, this is either true by definition, or a consequence of the fact that $Q$ is $\mathrm{Sp}_4(ℂ)$-invariant.

Comment: Thanks for this response. I have one doubt though. This might sound silly, but will you mind explaining how the correspondence occur between the bilinear form being lie algebra invariance and lie group invariance. I mean how do you get one condition from another.

Comment: Great answer! I had related discussions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3701479/96384.

Comment: @simutiyam That comes from differentiating the Lie group condition: let $g =\exp(tx)$ and differentiate $B(gv,gw)=B(v,w)$ which yields $B(xv,w) + B(v,xw) =0$. Note this is basically just product rule.